# How does spring autowire generic converters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, generics, autowired

Occasionally I've noticed interesting thing:

I've implemented spring `Converter` interface:

```
@Component
public class MyConverter implements Converter<MyClass1, MyClass2> {

    @Override
    public MyClass2 convert(MyClass1 source) {
       // doesn't matter
    }
}
```

In controller I autowire it like this

```
@Autowire
Converter<MyClass1, MyClass2> myConverter;
```

Surprise but spring inject proper class.

According my information spring autowires beans in runtime. Also I know that in Runtime generic types erasure.

I am tried to understand Spring soure but it hard for me.

Can you explain idea how does spring resolve this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though type erasure happens, *some* of the type-parameter information is not actually erased, but it's rather preserved elsewhere at Runtime.

For this class:

```
public class MyConverter implements Converter<MyClass1, MyClass2>
```

the parameterized types for the super-interface (`Converter`) are preserved, because the JVM should know that the compiled `MyConverter` implements an abstract method with a signature that actually *contains* these two types (`MyClass1` and `MyClass2`).

In order to demonstrate this, you can try out the following snippet in a simple `main` method - here, the parameterized information for the super-interface is restored at Runtime with Reflection:

```
Type[] interfaces = MyConverter.class.getGenericInterfaces();

ParameterizedType interfaceType = (ParameterizedType) interfaces[0];
Type[] types = interfaceType.getActualTypeArguments();

for (Type argument : types) {
    System.out.println(argument.getTypeName());
}
```

These Reflection-related classes (`Type`, `ParameterizedType`, etc.) are the ones which are actually being used by the Spring's [`ResovableType`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RC2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ResolvableType.html) class, which is responsible for *detecting* the best candidate for wiring, based on the provided type-information.

Comment: I'd like to add that information about type parameters are accessible from the `myConverter` field also (although not from the *value* of the field). That information can be matched against the one from the `MyConverter` class.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of what they describe in their blogpost [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics).

Quote,

> Starting with Spring Framework 4.0, Spring will automatically consider generics as a form of @Qualifier. Behind the scenes, the new [ResolvableType](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RC2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ResolvableType.html) class provides the logic of actually working with generic types. You can use it yourself to easily navigate and resolve type information.

So the answer is in [this class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/ResolvableType.java) and in [this class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/GenericTypeResolver.java) (and in [this class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/MethodParameter.java)).

Comment: This should be a comment rather then an answer.

Comment: as you can see in [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *Links to external resources are encouraged, **but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there**. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.*

Comment: The Spring Framework Core is actually quite a fascinating place. I should read it more often.